# Drag file or drag a file

Tags: grammar

I am working on some application, My first language is not English, I have some drag and drop box as attached bellow, I have 3 questions:

1+2: Is the marked field at the picture are ok? I'm not sure if I need to add the "  'a' file..."

3: When the user trying to drag more the one file I want to tell him that only file, I added the message screenshot, the messagק is fine?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some contexts it's OK to use a form of English in which articles are omitted to make the text more direct and concise.  You see this in newspaper headlines, for example.  So you could say

> Drag file to box below or click to select file

But you need to be consistent; either omit all the articles, or use all the articles:

> Drag a file to the box below or click to select a file

This is worded a bit oddly:

> Click or drop a file here.

It sounds like you're telling the user to either click a file there, or drop a file there.    To improve the wording, you could say:

> Click here or drop file here.

Finally, this needs an article:

> One file at **a** time only.

Comment: Your last sentence begs the question "why can't the word 'a' in 'at a time' be dropped in headlinese?"